# Transform Fama French Returns to Euro

Tags: currency, fama-french, return

I constructed a global portfolio and calculate it's daily return in Euro.

Now i want to do the regression with the Fama-French daily factor-returns (HML, SMB). However, these returns can only be found in USD on their website.

Can I simply convert the daily Fama-French returns into Euro with the following formula:

$$(1+r_{\mathrm{EUR}}) = (1 + r_\mathrm{{USD}}) \cdot (1+ r_{\mathrm{currency}})$$

where $r_{\mathrm{currency}}$ equals EUR/USD in time $t$, divided by EUR/USD in $t-1$, minus 1.

Answer (score 2):

#### I would recommend you to convert your global portfolio returns into US-$

---

Kenneth French provides several [global factor-returns](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_3developed.html) for the entire global stock market of developed countries. The description states, that

> all returns are in U.S. dollars, include dividends and capital gains, and are not continuously compounded.

Further:

> [...] The global portfolios use global size breaks, but we use the B/M breakpoints for the four regions to allocate the stocks of these regions to the global portfolios. [...]

So in fact, **before** calculating size- and book-to-market breakpoints, all these measures are converted into US-\$ instead of using local currencies. Therefore, i recommend you to convert your daily portfolio return into US-\$ (simple currency conversion) and apply your regression approach with US-$ portfolio returns. This is a common approach in international empirical research, as your results are based from the view of a US-investor and therefore your results are comparable to US-studies.

Furthermore, if you just convert the factor-returns from US-\$ into Euro, you would omit the fact, that the associated breakpoints and therefore the portfolio sort is based on variables measured in US-\$. This would bias your factor-exposure, so results are quite useless and not easily to interpret.

---

For local studies, it is often seen in some papers, that you use portfolio returns in local currency and replicate the Fama-French methodology for the specific country, i.e. you calculate your breakpoints in local currency and derive local factor-returns. However, for a global stock portfolio, this approach is quite inconvenient.

You may also take a look at [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/24301/29318) related question.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short...

Just think at the risk free rate (which is an essential part of Fama-French factors). 
It varies across currencies:

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/pdfiles/DSV2/Ch6.pdf

You do not get the risk free of another currency just by converting the risk free of a currency. Hence, what are trying to do with converted Fama-French factors?

Comment: This and your other answer are identical but the question is somewhat different, as such I feel that these answers don't answer the question as well as you could. Could you edit the answers so they become more specific?